# If the relationship is on to many, why with belongsTo i get an array?

Tags: php, laravel

Why belongsTo returns an array if the relationship is one to many?

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1288
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Models\Brand {#1289
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "brands"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:4 [
        "id" => 16
        "title" => "tenetur"
        "created_at" => "2022-03-09 18:54:32"
        "updated_at" => "2022-03-09 18:54:32"
      ]
      #original: array:4 [
        "id" => 16
        "title" => "tenetur"
        "created_at" => "2022-03-09 18:54:32"
        "updated_at" => "2022-03-09 18:54:32"
      ]
....
```

I understand that hasMany() relationships would return a model, so just for try and error I change belongsTo for hasOne on my Item model and it seems to expect for the Brands table to have an item_id but that doesn't make sense.

An Item has one and just one brand. And a Brand will have many items.

Items

```
+----------+----------------------------------------+-------+
| brand_id | sku                                    | price |
+----------+----------------------------------------+-------+
|       1  | Wuckert, Russel and Murray             |  6.52 |
|       2  | McGlynn Group                          | 34.69 |
|       2  | Walker-Murphy                          | 86.57 |
|       4  | Langworth PLC                          |  1.61 |
+----------+----------------------------------------+-------+
```

Brands

```
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | title        | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | impedit      | 2022-03-09 18:54:32 | 2022-03-09 18:54:32 |
|  2 | sit          | 2022-03-09 18:54:32 | 2022-03-09 18:54:32 |
|  3 | tenetur      | 2022-03-09 18:54:32 | 2022-03-09 18:54:32 |
|  4 | odio         | 2022-03-09 18:54:32 | 2022-03-09 18:54:32 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

My models are define in this way.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Brand extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    /**
     * Get the items associated with the brand.
     */
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    /**
     * Get the brand associated with the item.
     */
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, is not much of a problem i can just call my brand like "$newItem->brand()->get()[0]" but doesn't seem right and I want to undesrtand

Comment: You mean that the relationship `belongsTo` is returned in an array (collection of models)?

Comment: Yes, I will paste the response.

Comment: You can define a `hasOne` relationship (instead of `hasMany`) if that's more in line with your business logic

Comment: Because it's hasMany

Comment: If I define brand(){} on my Item model as both hasMany() or hasOne() it expects for the brands table to have an item_id which is wrong. Because one Item has one brand and a brand can have many items. So my foreign id is brand_id on my Items table.
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'brands.item_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `brands` where `brands`.`item_id` = 182 and `brands`.`item_id` is not null)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from your way of using brackets. Try it as

```
$newitem->brand;
```

Doku:  Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record using Eloquent's dynamic properties. Dynamic properties allow you to access relationship methods as if they were properties defined on the model: